# add class to manifest.xml

Tags: android

I'm trying to run the sample in this tutorial : http://www.devx.com/wireless/Article/42482/0/page/1?comment=61407-0#comment61407-0 
it seems to run fine in the emulator(I'm not sure cause the application uses the camera and it can't be shown in the emulator) . but when I try to run it on my device ( Nexus S) it forces to stop the application. the application has only two files , one main activity and another class called CustonCameraView.java which is used in the main activity . should I somehow add this class to the manifest.xml file ? 
thanks
this is my manifest.xml file :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      package="com.smtabatabaie.locationAR"
      android:versionCode="1"
      android:versionName="1.0">
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="10" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"></uses-permission>
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus" />

    <application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name">
        <!-- <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" /> -->
        <activity android:name=".main"
                  android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

    </application>
</manifest>
```

Comment: Could you please show us your current manifest-file?

Comment: Only activities, receivers and services should be necessary to add to the manifest file, views should not. Could you please tell us the output of LogCat when you run it on the device (thrown exceptions etc. from the app)? (in Eclipse: Window -> Show View -> LogCat)

Comment: there aren't many red lines in my LogCat, but the one I suspect is this with tag:"SurfaceFlinger" and Message:"texture=11, using format 17, which is not supported by the GL" .

Comment: I added the manifest.xml to the post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

have you added all necessary permissions to your manifest.xml?

according to http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.html you would have to add the following 3 permissions:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus" />
```

could you please add the Logcat error message so that we can see what is causing the force close in the first place?

Comment: with those permissions it runs but it says that the camera preview parameters are wrong . I have no idea which values should be used for previews , I have used 500 for height and 300 for width .